# File won't open for ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

Hi my professor posted this example to her website giving an example of ifstreams, how come I cant open any .txt file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>    // for setw
#include <fstream>    // for ifstream, ofstream

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char filename[25];      // a string for filename entry

   int val;        // for reading integers from file
   int sum = 0, count = 0;      
   double average;

   ifstream in1;        // create an input file stream

   do
   {
      in1.clear();
      cout << "Please enter the name of the input file.\n";
      cout << "Filename:  ";
      cin >> setw(25) >> filename;

      in1.open(filename);
      if (!in1)
         cout << "That is not a valid file.  Try again!\n";

   } while (!in1);

   // PROCESS THE INPUT FILE
   //  Read all integer values and compute average

   while (!in1.eof())        // while not end of file
   {
      in1 >> val;        // read an integer from file

      if (!in1.fail())       // in case last call failed to read an int
      {              //  due to trailing white space at end of file
    count++;
        sum += val;
      }
   }

   average = static_cast<double>(sum) / count;

   cout << "There were " << count << " numbers in the file\n";
   cout << "Sum = " << sum << "\t\tAverage = " << average << "\n\n";

   in1.close();

   return 0;
}
```

This is extremely aggravating! Is it a problem with my computer or something?

Blockquote

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more information to help you - what exactly happens when you run this code?

Comment: Did you try with an absolute path?

Comment: When i run the code it prompts me to enter a file name, however it tells me it can never find the file I enter

Comment: For example, I have a .txt file called "numbers.txt" that has a simple list of numbers in it. Whenever I type that in it tells me that file doesn't exist

Comment: And does the file exist and is it in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: There might actually be *other* problems that can cause the opening of the file to fail.

Comment: Also, don't do `while (!in1.eof())`, that won't work as you expect it to because the `eofbit` flag will not be set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file, causing the loop to iterate once too many. Instead do e.g. `while (in1 >> val)`.

Comment: @Demomomo Please hard-code the name of the file in your program.  We don't know what is really behind that `filename` variable.  If when you hardcode the name in your program, the file opens successfully, then there is a problem with your input statement, not with opening the file.

Answer (score 2):

Let me make two assumptions: you are using some IDE and you are using relative paths.

IDEs often execute your binary from a directory different than the project main dir. Try using absolute paths, find the right directory or run the file yourself.

Comment: I have tried using the absolute path and it still tells me the file does not exist. Also I am using Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Can you hardcode the file path in the code and tell me if it works please?

Comment: Still does not work :(

Comment: Please update your question with the updated version of your program that has the hard-coded string.  If the hard-coded file name does not work, that means that the file either does not exist, you entered an incorrect name, or you don't have permission to open the file.

Comment: And fyi, the default working directory for an MS DevStudio debug-run is the folder containing the *project* file (.vcprojx). Unless you've purposely changed it via project configuration, if you put your file there, and open it as `"filename.ext" with *no* slashes or path components, it should work, assuming you have proper permission to both the folder (which you better) and the file (which only you know for sure).

Comment: the absolute path is C:/Users/Demetri/Downloads/numbers.txt and i put it where "filename" went when trying to open the file

Comment: @Demomomo Please show the code, don't describe.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should start do do, is to write code to understand the error.  It's not only for you now, to debug, but also for users later on when they will encounter problems:

```
    ....
    if (!in1) {  // replace this bloc
        cout << filename << " is not a valid file\n";  // print filename to find out any issues (truncated name, etc...) 
        cout << "Error code: " << strerror(errno)<<endl; // Get some system info as to why
        char cwd[512];                           // print current working directory. 
        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));                // in case your path is relative 
        cout << "Current directory is " << cwd << endl;
        cout << "Try again !\n";
    }
```

Please note that `getcwd()` works as under linux, but in windows, you'll have to use `_getcwd()` instead.

**IMPORTANT REMARK:**

The following is not causing your error, but it might cause problems later on:

```
  while (!in1.eof()) {       // while not end of file
      in1 >> val;           // read an integer from file
      ...
```

prefer the following:

```
  while (in1 >> val) {       // while read of file works 
      ...
```

Browse arround on SO: there are lots of questions/answers that explain why.